# What should be the criteria for recommendation for MVP Category - Ambassador?

Tags: community, mvp

We have a category for recommending MVP as Ambassador. What should be the criteria?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The qualities that are considered when selecting an Ambassador MVP:

- Knows the latest Sitecore offering
- Drives business to Sitecore and ecosystem
- Actively participates in the Sitecore Advisory Councils
- Internal or external Ambassador of Sitecore
- Provides product feedback
- Supplies references and case studies

Source: https://mvp.sitecore.com/about

Comment: How sitecore knows candidate knows latest offerings and how can we participate in sitecore advisory councils?

Comment: The local and regional representatives of Sitecore are working together with these individuals regularly so they can judge their knowledge of the products. The advisory councils are invite only, but if this criteria is not met by someone still can be nominated and if selected might be invited.

Answer (score 4):

According to the announcement on Sitecore community the ambassadors are selected based on the following criteria

Ambassador: An individual with solid knowledge of the latest Sitecore offering who provide value for Sitecore, by influencing partners, industry, customers and decision makers and who provides product feedback, supplies references and case studies.

https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/13/t/8385

Answer (score 1):

According to Sitecore-  Who partner with Sitecore executives to provide insights and feedback specific to product road-map and strategy, as well as actively participate in a broad set of other community events and engagements.

We can consider them consultants who provide feedback and influence customers and partners.